# What is the so called "type-safe linkage" in C++?

Tags: c++

In the book Thinking in C++, it mentioned about type-safe linkage, but not very clear.Can someone explain it in detail?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should probably go on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typesafe linkage enforces the right number and type of parameters are passed at link time.

For example, in C, you can define a library function as taking an int, but through a series of mishaps, you can pass it a string.

C++ avoids this kind of error by **making function prototypes mandatory** and my using name mangling to enforce typesafe linking.[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/12851/)

Lets see by one example

```
//:Def.cpp
void f(int) {}

//Use.cpp
// Function misdeclaration
void f(char);

int main() {
  f(1); // Causes a linker error
}
```

function is actually `f(int)`, the compiler doesn’t know this because it was told through an explicit declaration – that the function is f(char).compilation will be successful. In C, the linker would also be successful, but not in C++.

A very detailed explanation is also given here http://www.hpc.unimelb.edu.au/nec/g1af05e/chap9.html

Comment: Please reveal your source, which is [What are type safe linkage?](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/12851/)

Comment: Strictly speaking: C++ doesn't require name mangling (and there are better solutions _if_ you can modify the linker).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Damn "modify the linker".That sounds interesting :)

Comment: When people speak of "type safe linking", they typically mean type safe linking with existing (designed for C) linkers.  But if you think about it: there's no reason this information has to be mangled into the function name (nor why it wouldn't be present on variables); most modern object formats are designed for C, and don't have fields for this sort of information, but there's no real reason why not.

Comment: So the compiler (both in C and C++) can not find this bug, but the link (only in C++) can stop to warn you. Did I get your point : )

Answer (score 1):

Type-safe linkage enforces that one has to provide the correct number and types of arguments at link-time. As a counter-example consider C, where you can define a function which takes an `double` but you accidentally pass a `complex`. In C++ this cannot happen due to type-safe linkage. As reference, have a look at [Type-Safe Linkage for C++](http://www.hpc.unimelb.edu.au/nec/g1af05e/chap9.html)

**Edit** wrapup: C++ uses name mangling. This also enables overloading of functions, where the function signature must be unique.

Comment: I think I got your point, I will read the reference.Thanks a lot. :)